# why element form and its child element hide slowly when setting attribute visibility:hidden on form?

Tags: css, angular, forms

is anybody knows that why element form and its child element hide slowly when setting visibility:hidden to form, while form and its child element hide fast when setting display:none to form. If element form and its child element hide slowly, user experience is not good

I looked up the information, but it was all about whether or not the dom tree was affected, not how the element form and its child element have been renderered.
The scene can be reproduced on this site:https://ng.ant.design/components/form/en#components-form-demo-horizontal-login, the first example in the page is the problem I encountered, you can press F12 to test what I see.
here is a img and a gif may help you understand the scean:

[enter link description here](https://ng.ant.design/components/form/en#components-form-demo-horizontal-login)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that somewhere you have a `transition` proprty set on the form element.

What this does is tell the browser to transition the change in styles.
`visibility` is an animate-able property while `display` is not.

Thats why you see it only with `visibility`.

Try setting this:
`transition: none!important` if it stops happening its confirmed.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I tried but not working, I set transition:none !important to form and its child element

Comment: when I set visibility:hidden, the icon in the input group is the first to disappear, then  the input element and btn

Comment: Can you go to `computed` styles and see what the transition is set to. Also try
*,
*:before,
*:after {
   transition: none!important
}

Comment: thanks, I think you're right, I looked up the source code of form element in ng-zorro-antd,then  I found the transition code in the less file(transition: color 0.3s @ease-out; // sync input color transition),the link:https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/form/style/index.less

Comment: Its not the form element, its the input element that has a attribute of transition(transition: all 0.3s), which has been overridden by nz-input directive of ng-zorro. thank u.

Comment: when I add transition:none !important to input element, everything goes right, the form element hide fast when visibility:hidden with no delay.